# File associations in Github for Windows

Tags: github, github-for-windows, file-association

Is there a way to choose what programs open what file types in Github for Windows? For example, I have text files (.txt) associated with Sublime Text, but Github for Windows opens them in Notepad.

Answer (score 0):

Check what you have configured for `.txt` files under the Default Programs:

1. Open Default Programs by clicking the Start button, and then clicking Default Programs.
2. Click Associate a file type or protocol with a program.
3. Click the file type or protocol that you want the program to act as the default for.
4. Click Change program.
5. Find Sublime Text

Comment: Thank you for the answer! But, as I wrote in my question, my file associations are OK. Text files (.txt) are already associated with Sublime Text. Similarly, Matlab code files (.m) are associated with Matlab. Nevertheless, both files of both types open in Notepad when I open them **from within** Github for Windows.

Comment: We're not doing anything custom here, just leveraging Windows for these file extensions (tell `explorer.exe` to open the file). Hard to say without more details. Feel free to reach out to support@github.com - it'll find its way to myself and my team.